# sort first n element of array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I know how to sort an array by ascending order, but not quite catch it when just sort first n (in my case, 4) elements. I tried to add a count value and do-while loop but it still sort all the element. Any idea?

```
    do{

        for(i=0; i<size; i++){
            for(j=i+1; j<size; j++){
                if(arr[j] < arr[i]){
                    temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp;
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
      }while(count<5)
```

Comment: Where's the problem? Just set `size` to what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know how to sort an array by ascending order, but not quite catch it when just sort first `n` elements

***It's not much different***.

Instead of using `for` loop to sort elements of the whole array, use it only for first `n` elements by changing the value of `size` to the value of `n`

```
int n;           //variable to store the value of 'n'
scanf("%d", &n); //scan value of 'n'

size = n;        //assigning value of 'n' to 'size'

for(i=0; i < size; i++)
{
    for(j = i+1; j < size; j++)
    {
        if(arr[j] < arr[i])
        {
            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

or by

using `n` instead of `size` if you require value of `size` later in the program.

```
    int n;           //variable to store the value of 'n'
    scanf("%d", &n); //scan value of 'n'

    for(i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j = i+1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if(arr[j] < arr[i])
            {
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you should also check for `n<=size`

Comment: @rootTraveller yeah... there'd be other such things like `n > 0`, `n <= size`, I'm sure OP would take care of those issues himself. I'm just showing him a way to overcome his problem but in no way I'm providing a complete solution :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used `n` inside the `for` loop because I need the size of the array fixable. And can I have a suggestion if teacher ask only sort last `n` number?

Comment: Yup... it's easy. Just take input of value of `n` and start the loop from `i = size - n` an continue loop till `i < size`

Answer (score 0):

Your `do` loop doesn't have an obvious function. The only thing you need to do is set `size` to something different (less-or-equal) than the array size

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `do-while` loop for that.  Just update the value of `size` by `n` .

```
size = 4; //assign the value till you want to sort
for(i=0; i<size; i++){
    for(j=i+1; j<size; j++){
         if(arr[j] < arr[i]){
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `do-while` loop and replace `size` by 4 (as you've told that you want to sort 4 elements).

Answer (score 0):

In your case, control will go to the while-condition after sorting all the elements.so no need to add do-while.Only set size you want.                                int i,j,n=4,k,temp;
    int arr[]={3,5,1,7,9,1,2};

```
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=i+1; j<n; j++){
            if(arr[j] < arr[i]){
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;

            }
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array is getting sorted completed into do{} before coming to your while condition(count<5).
please check this one-
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter first n numbers to be sorted");
        int firstN=sc.nextInt();

```
    int arr[]={2,3,8,1,0,5,4};

    if(firstN<=arr.length)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<firstN; i++){
            for(int j=i+1; j<firstN; j++){
                if(arr[j] < arr[i]){
                    int temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp;

                }
            }
        }
    }
```